# Shared data for Amazon EC2 instances

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

To handle high traffic, I'm planning to scale out, run my web application (WordPress based) on some EC2 instances (I'm very new to AWS). The instances need to work on the same data (images, videos...).

I am thinking about using S3 as the storage for this shared data.

My questions are:

- If I use S3, do I need to write extra codes for my application to upload and get data to/from S3? Or there is a magic way to mount EC2 instances to S3, and after that EC2 instances can access S3 as accessing the local storage?
- I've heard that S3 is a bit slow since it is accessed through web services (if users upload files and it takes time to upload the files to S3). So is there any better way for storing shared data?

I've read some documents about the ability of scaling of Amazon EC2. But none of them mentions about how to handle shared data. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native facility to 'mount' an S3 bucket as storage to an EC2 instance, although there are several 3rd-party apps which offer mechanisms to make S3 storage available as a virtual drive or repository. Most of them offer a preset amount of free storage and then a tiered charging mechanism for larger amounts - Google for 'S3 storage interface' and take a look.

Whether you write code to use S3 through the API or use an interface layer, there will always be some latency between your app and the storage. That's a fact of physics and there's nothing you can do to eliminate the delay, because the S3 repository is not local to the EC2 cluster - so you will never achieve 'local' storage access speeds.

An alternative might be to use EBS which **is** local to your EC2 instance - it has different properties to S3 (for example, it does not offer edge locations for regionally-localised access) but is much faster for application use because it is inside the EC2 cluster and mounted as local storage.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But if I use EBS as the storage, the maximum storage of a folder is 1TB (can only mount 1 EBS to that folder). And other instances cannot access to this EBS. Do you know normally what people do in my case? How do they store huge data, while using some EC2 instances?

Answer (score 0):

You could mount S3 bucket onto all your EC2 instances. It's a 2-way mount so all your files will be synchronized. You could use [s3f3](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) to do the mounting.

I used this guide and set up mine pretty quick: [Mount S3 onto EC2](http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/03/08/how-to-mount-s3-bucket-in-linux-ec2-instance/)

If you are then concerned about speed, you can use [Amazon ElastiCache](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) or even use EBS as a cache drive.

Answer (score 0):

For starts you question lacks some details about your application architecture, but there are some possibilities.

First, if you project is medium-sized you could use **GlusterFS** on your main nodes as servers and clients at the same time (using native or NFS protocol), **RDS** **Multi-AZ** MySQL instance for DataBase. CloudFront as CDN with **CDN linker** or W3TC plugins. Also, put an ELB in front.
In this particular case I would recommend a couple **c3.large** instances at least.

Second, when your project would grow  - you should make instance AMI and created an auto-scaling group that would just connect to your main storage and compute instances. (Also consider lifting compute load from these rather small instances).

Things to consider additionally:

- Great WordPress article about WordPress clusters for is http://harish11g.blogspot.ru/2012/01/scaling-wordpress-aws-amazon-ec2-high.html
- Alternative to GlusterFS solution could be **Ceph File System**
- You also could (or maybe should) you SSD cache (for example **flashcache**) for that GlusterFS volume.